# Changing size of the canvas makes it blurry

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, chart.js

I am changing the graph size upon the click for a better and overall view of m data for the pdf. But the problem is when i click to resize the canvas element it makes it blury and fuzzy. I am doing `$('canvas').css("width","811");`upon the click it however changed the size but makes the graph in the canvas blurry. I have read many posts but did not find a particular solution. Any help ?

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0kL8zkk/11/)

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: @Quince yeah let me add the fiddle it will take a while to make a fiddle.

Comment: set the canvas width and height property to change the resolution eg var can =document.getElementById("canvasid"); can.width = 811;` same for height. Setting the CSS only changes the size not the resolution.

Comment: @Blindman67 i have tried that also and by doing that tthe chart disappears. after hovering 5 to 6 times t the canvas field it appears but stretched and blurry.

Comment: @Blindman67 i have tried that also and by doing that tthe chart disappears. after hovering 5 to 6 times t the canvas field it appears but stretched and blurry.

Comment: Your css units are not matching the canvas resolution. canvas.width is always in pixels as a number without postfix units `canvas.width = 811` while the style must be in a valid css unit `canvas.style.width = "811px"` if these do not match it will be blurry

Comment: @Quince I have update my answer also this is the link to [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0kL8zkk/11/)

Comment: @Blindman67 i have tried that too but did not get much help. can you help me with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0kL8zkk/11/)

Comment: You are setting the devicePixelRatio to 2 that means the canvas resolution must be 2 times that of the canvas size.

Comment: @Blindman67 i did not understand i set pixelratio for the better graph readability in the pdf

Comment: Where did you get these `811` and `390` values ? If you want to shrink your canvas for export, keep the correct ratio, something like `var $c = $('canvas');
  $c.css({width: 800, height: 800/$c[0].width * $c[0].height});` if you want it to be 800 px wide.

Comment: @Kaiido sir actually i want to shrink these on 811 and 390 because of pdf

Comment: Then you will distort your image. From the fiddle, canvas width is 4000px and height is 984px. If you want to shrink to 811px width, the shrinked height should be ~200px. If you want the output to be 811*390px, then you'd have to set the original width and height to this aspect-ratio (e.g `w: 4000, h: 1923.6` or `w: 2046.2, h: 984`). Any other value will either distort one of your graphs, either crop your graph (which is also possible but would require some more code). [Example of setting the original canvas to the correct AR](https://jsfiddle.net/kbp5tnL9/)

Comment: @Kaiido oh ok sir i understand, i searched and came to know that we have to maintain the aspect ratio. If i apply the max-height and max-width it then changed its graph to be at a aspect ratio. I was actually hoping that there is another solution so that i did not have to stretched the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Canvas to PDF with selected DPI using chart.js and html2pdf.js

To change the output resolution for the canvas in the PDF you need to set the DIP

From memory a A4 is ~11+ inch across in landscape and you want to fit 2000 pixels, So let have a margin total of 1+inch making the width of the graph 10". We can use the CSS unit size of points (72 points per inch) so the canvas size should be 72pt * 10" = 720pt across. Scale the height by the same amount.

Now to get the DPI divide the canvas.width by the size 2000 / 10 = 200.

But I am assuming you want higher than that. So let's do it more accurately.

```
const A4 = {  // looked this up with google
    width : 11.69,
    height : 8.27,
}
// using pts and inches (I dont like using CSS inches)
const points = 72; // points per inch
const graphWidth = 10; // in inches on the page.
const graphDPI = 300; // desired DPI
const aspect = 492/2000; // aspect of image

function generate_pdf(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('blanks_graph');
    canvas.width = graphWidth * graphDPI;
    canvas.height = Math.floor(canvas.width * aspect);
    canvas.style.width = (graphWidth * points) + "pt";
    canvas.style.height = Math.floor(graphWidth * points * aspect)+"pt";
    // add left margin to center graph.
    // you should remove the button and maybe put a margin on the top of
    // the canvas
    canvas.style.marginLeft = Math.floor(((A4.width - graphWidth) / 2) * points) + "pt"
    // changing the size needs to redraw the canvas
    redrawGraph();
    // the graph is drawn via a timeout event so will not be ready untill
    // after this function is done. Also there is the animation to avoid
    // So easy way is to just create the PDF with a timeout
    setTimeout(function(){
        var element = document.getElementById('main_data_div');
        html2pdf(element, {
            margin:       0,
            filename:     'myfile.pdf',
            image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas:  { dpi: graphDPI, letterRendering: true },
            jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'l' }
         });
        },
        3000 // 3 seconds to redraw and animate.
    );
}

function redrawGraph(){ // redraws the graph
                        // just wrap this function around the graph draw code
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply . Sir but the problem is i am making the canvas dynamically,based on data sometimes there can be 1 canvas and sometime there can be 8 canvas. which also mean i can have 8 graphs. So its not possible to get the element by id.

Comment: @adeel If an element has an id that id must be unique to the page, and thus possible to get each canvas evelemnt by id. Or there are many other ways to get the elements using selectors

Comment: yeah id is unique and i am actually making id in a loop. and other thing is you are doing it in the html2pdf side i want to do it on the html side so that it can be easily printable and viewable when i compress the chart.

Comment: @adeel for the canvases you will need to set them up via a loop.  For the rest that would be best as another question as the comments don't give much room to set out the problem and possible solutions.

Comment: Ok sir no problem i will search more about it to sort out the problem

Comment: A bit late, but maybe helpful for someone:  
You may want to explictly increase the DPI of your chart, using chart.js's option [device-pixel-ratio](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/device-pixel-ratio.html).